# In ASP.NET MVC(3), is there any attribute to force the view generator to don't display Property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, attributes

I have a model with some properties, but I just need some of them display in views like List view, also I need to display all of the properties in create or edit views so I can create a full data covered rows, is there any attribute to force the generator to don't display properties in List View. some thing like this `[Display(false)]` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Anwar was close, it's `[ScaffoldColumn(false)]`

Comment: with this attribute I can't see the property in all view's but I need display them in create or edit view's and just don't display them in List view is there any way to this?

Comment: You will just have to delete the code for those properties in the views

Comment: of course you right, but I interesting to do this pragmatically, and also there is a way with define custom attribute and T4 editing or define Template, but I search for any existing attribute. thanks

Answer (score 4):

Decorate your attribute with

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
[ScaffoldColumn(false)]
```

Comment: what is the assembly of this attribute? I can't find it

Comment: I believe it's actually ScaffoldColumn(false)